# Fundamental chiral representations of SU(2)

Tags: representation-theory, spin-geometry

During class we arrived to the statement that the $(1/2,0)$ or right-handed representation of SU(2) is realized by:
$$
R_R=\exp\left(i\theta^a\frac{\sigma^a}{2}-\eta^a\frac{\sigma^a}{2}\right)
$$
whereas for the (0,1/2) or left-handed we have:
$$
R_L=\exp\left(i\theta^a\frac{\sigma^a}{2}+\eta^a\frac{\sigma^a}{2}\right)
$$
where $\theta^a$ and $\eta^a$ indicate the structure constants and $\sigma^a$ are the Pauli matrices.

We also said that the two component spinor $\xi_R$ is right-handed if it transforms under the action of the Lorentz group according o the $(1/2,0)$ and same for the left-handed spinor $\eta_L$ and the $(0,1/2)$.

However I encountered a different approach in Landau-Lifshitz vol.IV of theoretical physics. Here it's stated that a spinor is a two component quantity $\xi^\alpha$ Lorentz-transforming according to a matrix $B$ with unit determinant:
$$
\xi'^\alpha = B^\alpha_\beta \xi^\beta.
$$
Then spinors with dotted indices are introduced, which transform according to the conjugate complex of the previous formula:
$$
\eta^{\dot{\alpha}} \sim \xi^{\alpha\ast}.
$$
The two are claimed to be algebraically independent and the statement is formulated that symmetric four-spinors of higher rank such as:
$$
\zeta^{\alpha_1 \alpha_2 \ldots \alpha_n \dot{\beta}_1 \dot{\beta}_2 \ldots \dot{\beta}_m}
$$
build up $(n+1)(m+1)$ irreducible representations of the Lorentz group. This means the $\xi$ and the $\eta$ of Landau should be the same as my class' $\xi_R$ and $\eta_L$. However the transformation laws we used are not the conjugate complex of one another!

Furthermore we proved that $R_R^\ast$ is unitarily equivalent to $R_R$ through $\exp(i\sigma^2)$.

So how can the two definitions match?

Thanks

EDIT:
I think I figured out something.
The thing with dotted indices is that while, under a Lorentz transformation, the spinors with non-dotted or dotted TOP indices transform as:
$$
\xi^{{\alpha}}=R^{{\alpha}}_{{\beta}}\xi^\beta
$$
$$
\eta'^{\dot{\alpha}}=R^{\ast\dot{\alpha}}_{\ \ \dot{\beta}}\eta^{\dot{\alpha}}
$$
so this is indeed the complex conjugate representation, the spinors with non-dotted or dotted BOTTOM indices follow the rule:
$$
\xi_\alpha = g_{\alpha\beta}\xi^\beta;\qquad \eta_{\dot{\alpha}}=g_{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}}\eta^{\dot{\beta}}
$$
where
$$
g_{\alpha\beta}=g_{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}}=\left(
      \begin{array}{cc}
        0 & 1  \\
        -1& 0 \\
       \end{array} \right).
$$
Furthermore the bi-spinor or Dirac spinor, which is made up of Right and Left component is defined to be:
$$
\psi = \left(
      \begin{array}{c}
        \xi^\alpha   \\
        \eta_{\dot{\alpha}} \\
       \end{array} \right)
$$
which means the correct identification should be:
$$
\xi_R=\xi^\alpha; \qquad \eta_L=\eta_{\dot{\alpha}}.
$$
Am I getting this right?